# Max of column and index as tuples

Tags: python, pandas

My df with Index on first column:

```
      someD    Amount  Finals  
9      14      8831    2726
10     09      9731    3728
11     22      5431    1724
.
.
.
```

I am trying to return a tuple, which contains the max() value from column "Finals" with the corresponding Index.

So far I have:

```
df.loc[df['Finals'].idxmax()]
```

Which returns the entire row and the max value(Finals)

```
someD    09
Amount   9731 
Finals   3728                     
Name: 10, dtype: float64
```

How can I return a tuple of the form (Index, Finals), i.e.:

```
mytuple = ('10', '3728')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [Series.agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.agg.html) method:

```
In [49]: tuple(df['Finals'].agg(['idxmax','max']).values)
Out[49]: (10, 3728)
```

**UPDATE:** using `df.loc[]`:

```
In [74]: tuple(df.loc[[df['Finals'].idxmax()], 'Finals'].reset_index().values[0])
Out[74]: (10, 3728)
```

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of modification of my query - just for my clarity: why is .agg() required and it won't work with my initial attempt?

Comment: @Peter, i've chosen `.agg()` because other variants seem to require more verbose syntax. I've added another option, which is pretty similar to your attempt...

Answer (score 3):

Create tuples by scalars:

```
a = df['Finals'].idxmax()
b = df['Finals'].max()

mytuple = (a, b)
```

Or use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and convert `Series` to `tuple`:

```
mytuple = tuple(df['Finals'].apply(['idxmax','max']))
print (mytuple)
(10, 3728)
```